# How to get rid of gray space in button?

Tags: android, android-drawable

[Button with gray space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FmK5.png)
[Button with gray space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kq4Am.png)
Hi everyone, I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to get rid of a gray space inside my button. I would greatly appreciate the help.

Here is my code for my drawable and button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonLogIn"
    android:layout_width="300dp"

    android:layout_height="60dp"

    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonReg"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/buttonpink"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="LOG IN"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="30dp" />


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners android:radius="100dp" />
<stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/pink" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add the color to the shape in your drawable using like this

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="@color/your_color" />
  <corners android:radius="100dp" />
  <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="@color/pink" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thank you the reply! I did try by using a transparent color and the gray shade still appears.